# Android authentication and Web

Tags: android

I set up Contacts and Synchronization in the application I am developing. Authentication works in directly to the web site using DefaultHttpClient. That means I need to store cookies and every time user does something send it to server using that cookie. What is the better way to store the cookies? It seems CookieSyncManager only works with WebView. Or can I use it with DefaultHttpClient?

Comment: Means are you talking about to store username and password once user is successful with login?

Comment: No, I am asking about what is the best way to authenticate user. Directly to the web site or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In the webview, there is a setting. I think this may help you:

```
WebSettings.setSavePassword(boolean save);
```

Comment: In my app, I do not use WebView.